# How do spheres curve in hyperbolic space?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

The surface of a sphere embedded in Euclidean space has positive curvature and (eponymous) spherical geometry.

But what if I construct an $n$-sphere (e.g., a 2-sphere), defined as the set of points equidistant from some center point, in a negatively-curved $n+1$-dimensional hyperbolic space (e.g., $H^3$)? Does such a surface still always have positive curvature?

In other words, would a person walking around on a planet in a hyperbolic universe feel like they were walking around on a normal Euclidean planet, or would they feel like they were getting lost in a game of HyperRogue? Or does it depend on the size of the planet?

Comment: This is a good question to ask. I suggest starting by looking a Riemannian geometry textbook and reading about the exponential map and the geometry of geodesic spheres.

Comment: @Deane Should I infer from this comment that there is an answer that I would find in such a textbook, or that it is an open question which such a textbook would give me the tools to investigate?

Comment: A textbook would give you the tools to answer the question. It may or may not provide an explicit answer to your question. Somone is likely to provide a well explained detailed answer here, but, even so, it's a useful exercise to try to figure out the answer yourself before reading an answer, even if you don't succeed. You will appreciate the answer much more after you try it yourself. Of course, if you succeed without reading an answer, that's even better.

Comment: In euclidean space, any surface with a positive lower bound on its curvature is finite. In hyperbolic space, even if the surface is of positive curvature, if the lower bound is not great enough to "overcome" the intrinsic negative curvature of the space, then it is infinite. So you can have infinitely large planets that locally are still curved like Earth is (ie. it's of constant positive curvature but still goes on forever like a flat plane would in euclidean space).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model
.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horocycle

Comment: @user3257842: What you wrote in your comment is actually quite false.  Myers theorem is **intrinsic**: If the Ricci curvature on a complete Riemannian manifold is bounded from below by a positive constant, then the diameter of the manifold is bounded from above. I think, you are confusing the intrinsic and extrinsic curvature: Horospheres are intrinsically flat but extrinsically have constant positive curvature.

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking of the extrinsic curvature. If you're in a hyperbolic space and standing on a point of a horosphere, you'll still see it curve inwards away from you, just as you would standing on an ordinary sphere in euclidean space. From that you measure the second fundamental form and positive extrinsic curvature. To compute its intrinsic curvature you add that to the hyperbolic curvature of the tangent plane (derived from the ambient hyperbolic space).

Comment: A more correct statement would be objects in hyperbolic space have lower curvature than they appear. So what "looks" like an ordinary sphere (by measuring extrinsic curvature) can actually intrinsically be a bigger sphere or a flat plane, or just a hyperbolic plane of higher curvature than the ambient (negatively curved) space. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form#Generalization_to_arbitrary_codimension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me describe steps for proving this for the 2-dimensional hyperbolic spheres; I will leave you the higher dimensional case as an exercise:

1. Prove that all 2-dimensional geodesic spheres of the same radius in $H^3$ are congruent to each other.
2. Working with the unit ball model of $H^3$ check that $O(3)$ is the stabilizer of the center $0$ of the unit ball in the isometry group of $H^3$.
3. Check that $O(3)$ acts transitively on every hyperbolic sphere $S(0,R)$ of radius $R$  centered at $0$.
4. Using 3, prove that every  $S(0,R)$ has constant Gaussian curvature.
5. Use the Gauss-Bonnet formula, or Killing-Hopf theorem or other tools you know, to conclude that $S(0,R)$ has positive curvature.

If you like, I can give an explicit curvature formula using hyperbolic trigonometry.